# Android: Do I just have one shot per property through the use of themes? Is there nothing like CSS in Android?

Tags: android, themes, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles) they write:

> To apply a style definition as a theme, you must apply the style to an Activity or application in the Android manifest. When you do so, every View within the
>   Activity or application will apply
>   each property that it supports. For
>   example, if you apply the CodeFont
>   style from the previous examples to an
>   Activity, then all View elements that
>   support the text style properties will
>   apply them.

So, when I set TextColor to Red, do ALL Elements with Text change to red?? Arent there powerful specifier like in CSS style-sheets? I just see the concept of styles (`style="@style/CodeFont"`) practicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your comments you might find what your looking for with the property `textAppearance`.

Open the themes.xml file here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

If you do a find for textAppearance you notice various entries such as:

```
<style name="Theme">
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button</item>
    ...
    <item name="panelTextAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceInverse</item>
    ...
```

This allows you to some extent to style Components throughout your application as shown in the Maragues example.

So whilst its not possible to fully control the style of all child elements withint say a listview, scroll view etc, there is some limited support for controlling the styles some Text based components such as the TextView and or Button.

Comment: This is the right direction but how do you change the appearance of a property, such as textColor. I tried creating a new style that inherits from TextAppearance.Widget.Button and overriding textColor, but it didn't have any effect

Comment: (I set the textAppearanceButton property to point to the new style too)

Answer (score 2):

If you read just below the text you quoted:

*To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the AndroidManifest.xml file and edit the  tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name*

*If you want a theme applied to just one Activity in your application, then add the android:theme attribute to the  tag instead.*

And a little bit after that, it describes how to inherit and override properties, just like CSS:

*If you like a theme, but want to tweak it, just add the theme as the parent of your custom theme. For example, you can modify the traditional dialog theme to use your own background image like this:*

```
<style name="CustomTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background</item>
</style>
```

Then, to interit from CustomTextView

```
<style name="CustomTextView.RedText">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item> 
</style>
```

Once designing the XML layout, you can inherit a theme and override the properties

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/example"

    style="@style/CustomTextView.RedText"

    android:textColor="@color/green" />
```

I think you should read again the page you yourself linked, it's well explained :)

Comment: So, in both cases, I have to set the style attribute in the actual element?

Comment: You can also set the style in the manifest. An <activity> or an <application> may have a theme, which can be overridden later.

Comment: So, what can I style, when setting a theme to an activity? Can I say smth like "All Buttons have red Text and all TextViews have blue, small Characters"? You know what I mean by refering to CSS?

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, I know the basis. In Android, I don't think you can define "All buttons have red text" in a theme. You can create a template like <style name="MyButton" parent=".../Widget.Button"> and then each time you use a button set the style=@style/MyButton. It would be interesting if you could define a set of themes in a .xml and then apply it to the application, but I've never seen that.

Comment: OK, so far I don't see any benefit of using themes compared to styles because they are too unspecified. Nobody wants all text to be red in his app. For my opinion it just makes sense for attributes like background.